# UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions error while executing query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query returns the number of tickets which have been open older than 72 hours.
Need to understand the reason for this error and a possible solution to this post.Could anyone please help?

I get the following error while running this query:

```
Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.
```

Below given is the code:

```
 SELECT temp1.*, max(cast(Round(temp2.Plan_Val,0) as int)) as Plan_Val,max(cast(Round(temp2.actual,0) as int)) as actual_val FROM(
        SELECT t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)], REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE,[Assigned Tech],NAME , Job_ticket_id FROM (
        SELECT '%Tickets Open Older than 72 Business Hours' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],[Problem_Type_Name(Child)], REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE,[Assigned Tech],NAME , Job_ticket_id
        FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE

        UNION

        SELECT '%Tickets Open Older than 72 Business Hours' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],[Problem_Type_Name(Child)], REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE,[Assigned Tech],NAME , Job_ticket_id
        FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE
        WHERE [greater than 72 hours] <= 4320) t

        group by t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] , t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE,[Assigned Tech],NAME , Job_ticket_id) temp1

        INNER JOIN


        (SELECT t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],case when sum(t.Total_tickets) = 0 then null else cast(Round((cast(sum(t.Total_tickets) as decimal(38,2))- cast(sum(t.Alarm_Val) as decimal(38,2)))/cast(sum(t.Total_tickets) as decimal(38,2))*100,0) as int) end as Plan_val, 0 as actual  FROM (
        SELECT '%Tickets Open Older than 72 Business Hours' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],0 as Alarm_Val, count(distinct [Job_ticket_id])/29 as Total_tickets 
        FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE
        group by [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] 

        UNION

        SELECT '%Tickets Open Older than 72 Business Hours' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],count(distinct [Job_ticket_id])/29 as Alarm_Val, 0 as Total_tickets 
        FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE
        WHERE [greater than 72 hours] <= 4320
        group by [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] ) t
        group by t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] 

        UNION
        SELECT t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],0 AS plan_val, cast(Round((cast(sum(t.Total_tickets) as decimal(38,2))- cast(sum(t.Alarm_Val) as decimal(38,2)))/cast(sum(t.Total_tickets) as decimal(38,2))*100,0) as int) as actual  FROM (
        SELECT '%Tickets Open Older than 72 Business Hours' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],0 as Alarm_Val, count(distinct [Job_ticket_id])/4 as Total_tickets 
        FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE_month
        group by [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] 

        UNION

        SELECT '%Tickets Open Older than 72 Business Hours' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],count(distinct [Job_ticket_id])/4 as Alarm_Val, 0 as Total_tickets 
        FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE_month
        WHERE [greater than 72 hours] <= 4320
        group by [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] ) t

        group by t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)]) temp2

        ON temp1.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]=temp2.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
        Group by temp1.[Assigned Tech],temp1.Close_Date,temp1.Job_ticket_id,temp1.NAME,temp1.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],temp1.Report_Date,temp1.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)]
```

Comment: If you union selects *each* select must return he same number of columns (and be of a compatible type) - if this was not the case you would have a jagged result set which is not representable.

Comment: And what part of the error message is not clear?

Comment: The error message is clear but i am not able to understand which part of this query is causing this error @GordonLinoff

Comment: There are so many things in here that are just bad. A column named [greater than 72 hours]. Seriously? And then you have to check if the value is less than 4320...by the name of the column it should never be less right? Then the unions...you select all rows from a table and UNION it to a subset...the result is the entire table. I would start with a new query, this needs a complete overhaul.

Comment: Count the columns in EACH select statement, by running them separately...When you can confirm that each Select statement has the same number (and type) of columns, then and only then - add them together with Union

Comment: @SeanLange 4320 is in minutes which is 72 hours

Comment: Yeah I understand that...but the column is named [greater than 72 hours]. The name sounds like a bit but you are using to store some sort of value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is why I suggest you might want to start over. You have the following code to produce "temp1"

```
SELECT t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
              , t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)]
              , REPORT_DATE
              , CLOSE_DATE
              , [Assigned Tech]
              , NAME
              , Job_ticket_id
FROM   (SELECT '%Tickets Open Older than 72 Business Hours' AS [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
                      , [Problem_Type_Name(Child)]
                      , REPORT_DATE
                      , CLOSE_DATE
                      , [Assigned Tech]
                      , NAME
                      , Job_ticket_id
               FROM   TEMP_TICKET_STATE
               UNION
               SELECT '%Tickets Open Older than 72 Business Hours' AS [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
                      , [Problem_Type_Name(Child)]
                      , REPORT_DATE
                      , CLOSE_DATE
                      , [Assigned Tech]
                      , NAME
                      , Job_ticket_id
               FROM   TEMP_TICKET_STATE
               WHERE  [greater than 72 hours] <= 4320) t
       GROUP  BY t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
                 , t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)]
                 , REPORT_DATE
                 , CLOSE_DATE
                 , [Assigned Tech]
                 , NAME
                 , Job_ticket_id) temp1
```

This entire thing can be reduced to a single, simple query like this.

```
SELECT '%Tickets Open Older than 72 Business Hours' AS [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
    , [Problem_Type_Name(Child)]
    , REPORT_DATE
    , CLOSE_DATE
    , [Assigned Tech]
    , NAME
    , Job_ticket_id
FROM   TEMP_TICKET_STATE temp1
GROUP BY temp1.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)]
    , temp1.REPORT_DATE
    , temp1.CLOSE_DATE
    , temp1.[Assigned Tech]
    , temp1.NAME
    , temp1.Job_ticket_id
```

You can do the same type of simplification on temp2. In general this is just way more complicated than it needs to be.

--EDIT--

Here is your second query with much of the noise removed so you can the skeleton.

```
SELECT t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
    , t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)]
    , CASE WHEN Sum(t.Total_tickets) = 0 THEN NULL /*bunch of stuff here removed*/END AS Plan_val
    , 0 AS actual
FROM   
--[A bunch of stuff here]

UNION
SELECT t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
    --Where is [Problem_Type_Name(Child)]??
    , 0 AS plan_val
    , Cast(0/*bunch of stuff here removed*/ AS INT) AS actual
FROM 
(
---A bunch of stuff here]
) t
GROUP  BY t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
    , t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)]) temp2
```

I would really recommend using sensible column names. Avoid using parenthesis, reserved words and other characters that are painful to work with. The column names are used for developers and if you want to provide more descriptive names or formatting that should be done in the application.

For example. Instead of "Problem_Type_Name(Parent)" how about something like ProblemTypeParent. It is still quite clear what that means but removes all the ugliness and the requirement to use [] around the name. Some people like underscores and others don't. I find I don't like the extra 2 keystrokes for little benefit. I do use them occasionally but not always. I tend to prefer Pascal case. But that stuff is all preference. Above all be consistent.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange I will try to simplify this query again.

Comment: Could you please help me with the Temp2 as well? I am not able to get rid of this error.

Comment: I can't even begin to help. The code is so horrific to read. You have nested selects all over the place and all kinds of craziness. You need to start by turning that abomination into something somebody can decipher. I apologize for the harsh words but I just spent 20 minutes trying to break that into smaller chunks and it is just a nightmare. Formatting, nested selects, unbelievably horrid column names. UGH!!!

Comment: I understand your point of view. But please understand that I am still learning and trying to improve. An expert like you can help me learn from my mistakes. It would be great if you could help me with this query which I could then take forward with me.

Comment: The trick is you have to break this massive query into pieces so you can see what is going on. Once you do this is becomes painfully obvious where the issue is.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I have noted all the points mentioned by you and will work towards it. thanks again!